# How to make the search function work when the file is inside a model which is inside of another model

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-filter

I use python and Django 2.2.9 with Django-filter 2.1.0, and I want to add some search function for the website.

My database looks like this:

[image: User database]

Upper is the 'User' database, the downer is the 'Entry' database.

[image: Entry database]

Here are what I have in the filter.py:

```
import django_filters
from .models import *
from django_filters import CharFilter
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    username = CharFilter(field_name='username', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)


class EntryFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    locations = CharFilter(field_name='locations', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('locations',) # name
```

The search function for the 'username' works well, but the search for the location 'name' does not work. What I think is because the 'username' just in the 'User' model, but the 'name' of the locations is in the 'locations' model which is a model that inside another model called 'Entry'. So, I should try to make it search for something in the 'name' file which inside the 'locations' that inside the 'Entry', but I do not know how to make it.

And here is the model.py, I am not sure if I should make any change on it:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from djongo import models
from django import forms

# Create your models here.


class Locations(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    fendering_position = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    STS_position = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Cargos_permitted = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Type_of_operation = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Depth_of_water = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Approval_to_conduct_STS_issued_by = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Approval_needed_prior_to_each_STS_operation = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Vessel_sizes_permitted = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Night_time_berthing_permitted = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Is_local_piloting_assistance_required = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Are_tugs_required = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class EmergencyContacts(models.Model):
    Oil_Spill_Responders = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Local_Emergency_Medical_Assistance = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Police = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Coast_Guard = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Fire_fighting = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

class Equipment_Details(models.Model):
    Primary_Fenders = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Secondary_Fenders = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Fender_Moorings = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Rubber_Hoses = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Composite_Hoses = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

class Agent_Details(models.Model):
    Agent_Company = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Agent_Contact = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Fees_to_be_incurred_for_STS_Operations = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

class Base_Details(models.Model):
    Base_Location = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Storage_Space = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Security_Arrangements = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Closest_Airport = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Local_taxi_firms = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Accommodation = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Base_facilities = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

class Notice_Period(models.Model):
    Notice_Period = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Documentation_Requirements = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

class Support_Craft_Details(models.Model):
    Vessel_Name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Support_Craft_Owner = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Telephone = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

class Tug_Provider_Details(models.Model):
    Tug_Provider_Company = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Tug_Provider_Contact = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Tug_Provider_Vessel_Name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

class Area_Details(models.Model):
    Location_under_the_control_of_authorities = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Current_port_security_level = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    What_is_considered_port_limits = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    What_is_considered_international_waters = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Distance_from_support_base = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Transit_time_from_shore_to_STS_location = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Size_of_transfer_area = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Does_the_area_have_a_large_enough_run_in_area = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Is_the_transfer_area_sheltered = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Regulations_to_be_complied_during_the_operation = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Nature_of_seabed = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Average_depth_of_water = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    STS_location_suitable_for_anchoring = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Any_other_service_provider_in_the_same_vicinity = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

class Navigational_Hazards(models.Model):
    Local_marine_activity = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Any_physical_limitations_on_vessel_size = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Distance_from_land = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Any_other_navigational_hazards_in_the_area = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

class Met_Ocean_Conditions(models.Model):
    Prevailing_winds = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Predominant_current = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Average_wave_height = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Average_swell_height_and_period = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    What_is_the_tidal_range_if_applicable = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Location_subject_to_restrictive_Met_conditions = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    STS_Location_covered_by_forecasting_service = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

class Environmental_Details(models.Model):
    Location_adjacent_to_any_public_sensitive_areas = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Environmental_bodies_to_be_advised_of_operations = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Local_oil_pollution_prevention_requirements = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    STS_area_covered_by_oil_spill_organisation = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Contract_directly_with_an_Oil_pollution_contractor = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)


class LocationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Locations
        fields = [
                'name', 'fendering_position', 'STS_position', 'Cargos_permitted', 'Type_of_operation', 'Depth_of_water', 'Approval_to_conduct_STS_issued_by', 'Approval_needed_prior_to_each_STS_operation', 'Vessel_sizes_permitted', 'Night_time_berthing_permitted', 'Is_local_piloting_assistance_required', 'Are_tugs_required',
        ]

class EmergencyContactsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmergencyContacts
        fields = [
                'Oil_Spill_Responders', 'Local_Emergency_Medical_Assistance', 'Police', 'Coast_Guard', 'Fire_fighting',
        ]

class Equipment_DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Equipment_Details
        fields = [
                'Primary_Fenders', 'Secondary_Fenders', 'Fender_Moorings', 'Rubber_Hoses', 'Composite_Hoses',
        ]

class Agent_DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Agent_Details
        fields = [
                'Agent_Company', 'Agent_Contact', 'Fees_to_be_incurred_for_STS_Operations',
        ]

class Base_DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Base_Details
        fields = [
                'Base_Location', 'Storage_Space', 'Security_Arrangements', 'Closest_Airport', 'Local_taxi_firms', 'Accommodation', 'Base_facilities',
        ]

class Notice_PeriodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Notice_Period
        fields = [
                'Notice_Period', 'Documentation_Requirements',
        ]

class Support_Craft_DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Support_Craft_Details
        fields = [
                'Vessel_Name', 'Support_Craft_Owner', 'Telephone',
        ]

class Tug_Provider_DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tug_Provider_Details
        fields = [
                'Tug_Provider_Company', 'Tug_Provider_Contact', 'Tug_Provider_Vessel_Name',
        ]

class Area_DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Area_Details
        fields = [
                'Location_under_the_control_of_authorities', 'Current_port_security_level', 'What_is_considered_port_limits', 'What_is_considered_international_waters', 'Distance_from_support_base', 'Transit_time_from_shore_to_STS_location', 'Size_of_transfer_area', 'Does_the_area_have_a_large_enough_run_in_area', 'Is_the_transfer_area_sheltered', 'Regulations_to_be_complied_during_the_operation', 'Nature_of_seabed', 'Average_depth_of_water', 'STS_location_suitable_for_anchoring', 'Any_other_service_provider_in_the_same_vicinity',
        ]

class Navigational_HazardsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Navigational_Hazards
        fields = [
                'Local_marine_activity', 'Any_physical_limitations_on_vessel_size', 'Distance_from_land', 'Any_other_navigational_hazards_in_the_area',
        ]

class Met_Ocean_ConditionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Met_Ocean_Conditions
        fields = [
                'Prevailing_winds', 'Predominant_current', 'Average_wave_height', 'Average_swell_height_and_period', 'What_is_the_tidal_range_if_applicable', 'Location_subject_to_restrictive_Met_conditions', 'STS_Location_covered_by_forecasting_service',
        ]

class Environmental_DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Environmental_Details
        fields = [
                'Location_adjacent_to_any_public_sensitive_areas', 'Environmental_bodies_to_be_advised_of_operations', 'Local_oil_pollution_prevention_requirements', 'STS_area_covered_by_oil_spill_organisation', 'Contract_directly_with_an_Oil_pollution_contractor',
        ]


class Entry(models.Model):
    locations = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Locations),
        model_form_class=LocationsForm
    )

    emergencycontacts = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(EmergencyContacts),
        model_form_class=EmergencyContactsForm
    )

    equipment_details = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Equipment_Details),
        model_form_class=Equipment_DetailsForm
    )

    agent_details = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Agent_Details),
        model_form_class=Agent_DetailsForm
    )

    base_details = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Base_Details),
        model_form_class=Base_DetailsForm
    )

    notice_period = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Notice_Period),
        model_form_class=Notice_PeriodForm
    )

    support_craft_details = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Support_Craft_Details),
        model_form_class=Support_Craft_DetailsForm
    )

    tug_provider_details = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Tug_Provider_Details),
        model_form_class=Tug_Provider_DetailsForm
    )

    area_details = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Area_Details),
        model_form_class=Area_DetailsForm
    )

    navigational_hazards = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Navigational_Hazards),
        model_form_class=Navigational_HazardsForm
    )

    met_ocean_conditions = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Met_Ocean_Conditions),
        model_form_class=Met_Ocean_ConditionsForm
    )

    environmental_details = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Environmental_Details),
        model_form_class=Environmental_DetailsForm
    )


    objects = models.DjongoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.locations.name
```

If you can give me some suggestions, I really thankful for that.